# Is there a way to move passwords from "Default" to "Login" in seahorse?

Tags: wireless, password, seahorse

When I reinstalled Ubuntu, I logged in on my wifi and authenticated with a password that seahorse saved in "Default". But I want that in "Login" so that I won't have to enter my password twice everytime i reboot, how can that be done?

Answer (score 5):

From http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10945148&postcount=14

```
cd ~/.gnome2/keyrings
rm login.keyring
mv default.keyring login.keyring
echo -n "login" > default
```

(You may not need the last line, and I backed up the login.keyring rather than deleting it).

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From Network Connections.

Click on my Wireless that you connect to automatically when you boot up. Click Edit. And at the very bottom it has a box to make the connection available to all users. Check that box.

---Below is added by OP, text is in Swedish---

[image: Network manager selected in the panel]

Then

[image: Selecting wireless network]

And at last

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it still won't work!