# How to move keys to "Login" in seahorse?

Tags: 11.04, authentication, seahorse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to move passwords from “Default” to “Login” in seahorse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41912/is-there-a-way-to-move-passwords-from-default-to-login-in-seahorse)

I want to move a few passwords into "login" in Seahorse, so that I will authenticate them when I, well, login, but I can't drag n' drop them and don't know how to do this. Anyone who knows?

Comment: Do you want to create a new Password entry? Or move within Seahorse itself? Can you make your question a big more clear with some snapshots?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way built in to Seahorse for moving passwords between different keyrings--_You have to recreate them manually.

Comment: here is a link that is on the sameish topic
 http://askubuntu.com/questions/41912/is-there-a-way-to-move-passwords-from-default-to-login-in-seahorse